# Eclipse RCP - perspective not showing components

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am going through some RCP tutorials, it is quite difficult to work with RCP. I created a new RCP project using the "RCP application with a view" as my template, and it has generated a nice View class but there is just one problem and this is something that happens when I try to run any RCP project, that is when I run it as an eclipse application, it always gives the default eclipse view. I tried this tutorial here:

[Vogella RCP tutorials](http://vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse3RCP/article.html#views)

but everytime I run anything, it always goes into the default Eclipse view and no tutorial is telling me anything about it, it usually just says it should look like this. Could someone please help me understand what is going on and how to actually see this view that this template has generated for me.

Comment: Have you create an application using the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.application` extension point as described earlier in the tutorial? Are you running that Application?

Comment: @greg-449 I don't know what you mean by using org.eclipse.core.runtime.application... so no I guess I haven't. But what about when I just want to run the template as well...not just the tutorials, it seems as though there is a configuration I am missing or I don't understand it.

Comment: @greg-449 for example, I did the editor and ran it...I could see the editor, but in the main eclipse editor window with the "imagine" text, why can't I just see that view with the other views hidden away...my tool bars are missing too...they shouldn't be, but the main eclipse toolbar is there...

Comment: You are running a normal Eclipse rather than your RCP. You must create an application as described (rather too briefly) earlier in the tutorial. You must then make sure you run that application rather than the main Eclipse application. Note: If you are doing a new RCP and don't want to use any old Eclipse stuff the [Eclipse 4 RCP](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) is the way to go (but be sure to understand the limitations of what older code can be used).

Answer (score 1):

Before running the RCP application, you have to add a new product configuration to that. To do this right click on the project folder and select New->ProductConfiguration
Now you get a .product file in which you have to create the new application as the wizard will help you..